# How to check if a user HAD a permission before they left the server?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Since

```
onGuildMemberRemove()
```

is called when a members leaves, when trying to check if he had permission to view/speak in a specific channel, it returns that

```
textChannel.canTalk(event.getMember())
```

is empty / null

Please help me get around this.

Here is my

```
onGuildMemberRemove()
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < channelID.length; i++) {
    TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(channelID[i]);

    if (textChannel.canTalk(event.getMember()) && textChannel.getParentCategoryId().equals("1030472114907652137")) {
        textChannel.delete().queue();
        Arrays.stream(channelID).toList().remove(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add more detail to what `when a members leaves` means

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can only check roles, but channel overwrites are cleaned up on leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but i found the asnwer!

First declare an array of type PermissionOverride[] in the main method.

Then in the onGuildMemberJoin method:

```
    overrides = new PermissionOverride[overrides.length +1];
        overrides[overrides.length - 1] = event.getGuild()
                .getTextChannelById(textChannel.getId())
                .getPermissionContainer()
                .getPermissionOverrides()
                .get(0);
```

Now in the onGuildMemberRemove method i can simply check if what i am looking for exists in overrides[]

```
    public void onGuildMemberRemove(GuildMemberRemoveEvent event) {

        for(int k=0; k<event.getGuild().getCategoryById("1030472114907652137").getChannels().size(); k++) {
            for(int l = 0 ; l < overrides.length; l++){
                if(overrides[l].getChannel().getId().equals(event.getGuild().getCategoryById("1030472114907652137").getChannels().get(k).getId())) {
                    if (!overrides[l].getChannel().getId().equals(null)) {
                        overrides[l].getChannel().asTextChannel().delete().queue();

                        overrides = removeOverride(overrides, overrides[l]);

                        System.out.println(overrides);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For explanation i am creating a verification channel every time someone joins the server and grants them the VIEW_CHANNEL permission, then in case they leave before completing the verification, i remove the channel that they had access too.

In other words if you want to do it, you have to save the data in a PermissionOverride array, to access it when you need.

@Minn
Nothing is impossible.